# Faster way of comparing all data in list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a program that retrieves headlines from news websites, and using a function gets the similarity of these headlines and returns ones with a high similarity. My list of headlines looks like this:

```
[
{"headline": "Headline Example", source: "Source Example"},
{"headline": "Headline Example", source: "Source Example"},
{"headline": "Headline Example", source: "Source Example"},
...And so on
]
```

And I can append the pair to a list by doing this:

```
similarList = []

for i in headlines:

    for x in headlines:

        if similar(i["headline"], x["headline"]) > .6:
            
           similarList.append([i,x])
```

And this is the similar function:

```
# Checks similarity of 2 strings
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):

    # Returns value between 0 and 1
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

As many of you might point out, this code is long and redundant, but I don't really know any data sorting methods that could get it done quicker. Considering that this code with around 200 headlines takes over 10 seconds, this could be a problem. Are there any data sorting algorithms that might get it done quicker?

Comment: Unless you have some knowledge about the `similar()` function, I don't think there's much better you can do.

Answer (score 2):

We would need to see your code for the `similar()` function to see if it would be possible to complete this in `O(n)`. Although this would most likely be much more complicated than what you have now.

A simple performance improvement is to remove all the duplicate checks you are performing like this:

```
for iInd, i in enumerate(headlines):

    for xInd in range(iInd+1, len(headlines)):
        
        if similar(i["headline"], headlines[xInd]["headline"]) > .6:
            
           similarList.append([i,x])
```

Edit:

So it seems like you could probably use an m-dimensional hashmap to complete this in O(nlogn), or maybe even O(n) with the right implementation. m would scale with the max length of the headlines. This would be extremely memory intensive though.

Comment: You're assuming that `similar` is commutative and also that comparing something to itself for similarity is uninteresting. I won't blame you for this... :-) But strictly speaking, the list you're creating has fewer elements.

Comment: Just updated to show the similar function

Comment: Also, I'd use `for xInd in range(iInd+1, len(headlines))` instead of the second `for` loop, to avoid all the `continue`s, and have `x = headlines[xInd]`.

Comment: @nickie You're right that was an error on my part but it turned out okay. I'll edit the answer with your recommended change.

Comment: As I said, I'm still a beginner at algorithms and such. Any tips on implements an m-dimensional hashmap?

Comment: @mythiclisp There is really no easy way to complete this any faster, if you are a beginner you should just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

According to its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), `SequenceMatcher` runs in quadratic expected time (worst-case cubic, best-case linear). This means that the complexity of your original code is O(N^2 M^2), where N is the size of your array (the number of headlines) and M is the length of the strings (the length of the headlines). The rest of my answer makes sense if M is larger than your alphabet.

I would attempt to reduce the complexity by taking into account that we need the similarity ratio to be > 0.6. This requires the existence of some pretty long common part in the two strings. If you count the frequencies of characters in each string, and there are C common characters (counting duplicates) in a pair of strings, you only care for this pair if 2*C/(M1+M2) > 0.6. In case this happens, you have to check for similarity (which will cost M1*M2) but you will most probably save many checks.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is to check for enough common characters in a string before running the similar() function between them to reduce the time complexity

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got this working around 5x faster then before.